# How to zoomout barchart using highchart?

Tags: java, highcharts

I want to zoomout my barchart x-axis values.
I am dynamically created barchart from database values using struts2,my x-axis data is like city,population
etc.I want to do zoom my barchart data.

please provide me any solution

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setExtremes function which allows ot define set range on xAxis.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes()